# For commutative rings, if the ring of polynomials is a PID then the ring is an integral domain.

Tags: polynomials, principal-ideal-domains, integral-domain

I am reading Dummit and Foote's proof that if $R$ is a commutative ring, and if $R[x]$ is a PID, then $R$ is a field.  At the start of the proof they write

> Proof: Assume $R[x]$ is a Principal Ideal Domain. Since $R$ is a subring of $R[x]$ then
> $R$ must be an integral domain (recall that $R[x]$ has an identity if and only if $R$ does). ...

I understand how $R$ has an identity if and only if $R[x]$ does, but I don't see how this tells us that $R$ is an integral domain.

To try to work it out myself, if $a,b\in R$ and $ab=0$ then we need to relate this to the other assumptions, so perhaps we consider the ideal $(a,b)$ in $R[x]$.  Then there is some $c \in R$ such that $(c) = (a,b)$ and therefore $c = am+bn$ for some $m,n\in R$.  Then

$$ abn = 0 $$

$$ a(c-am) = 0 $$

$$ ac = a^2m $$

This seems to me a dead-end.  We are not guaranteed by anything that I can see, that there is a unitary element or a unit in any of these rings.

Comment: If $R$ is not a field then it has a non-zero proper ideal $(a)$ and $(a,x)$ is not principal in $R[x]$.

Comment: They simply use that a subring of a domain is a domain…

Comment: $R$ cannot have zero divisors since $R[x]$ doesn’t have any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that PID means Principal Ideal **Domain**.

If $A\subset B$ is an inclusion of rings and $B$ is a domain, $A$ must be as well because any relation
$$
xy=0
$$
in $A$ holds in $B$ too.